# How to popup the android permission dialog in advance under API 23?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-permissions

Is there any way to popup the camera permission dialog programmatically before open camera ?

The dialog as the following screenshot:
[image]

Comment: checkout this demo for android's permission https://github.com/nitiwari-dev/Android-M-RuntimePermissionDemo

Answer (score 0):

You can call camera intent in a dialog box positive button. and set the message for accessing camera in Alertdialog box.

Comment: In fact, i wan to know if there is way to popup the permission dialog programmatically but not by open camera. I want to let use choose the permission in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "new permission system" before API 23. The Dialog does not pop up before 23 either, as you will always get "granted" if asking for permission.

If you implement everything correctly, set permissions in the manifest and ask for them at rumtime (if not given) the app will behave correctly and users before 23 will just use it, users with API 23 and later will get a dialog the first time.

You can not "ask" the user on before if he wants to grant you the permission after upgrading to 23.

If you want to show a "first time dialog" an alert dialog and some sharedPreference setting "hasSeenDialog" is the way to go. But I don't see why you would need that.